# Django: Model class doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on implementing Django Rest Framework into my current Django project. I have followed the DRF tutorial/getting started guide and made some minor alterations to allow the drf code to work with my existing apps and models.

My problem is that I get the following error whenever I try to run the application:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f83fb31dd08>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
return check_method()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/python/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/vagrant/PROJECT/config/urls.py", line 26, in <module>
url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/python/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/vagrant/PROJECT/api/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
from . import views
  File "/vagrant/PROJECT/api/views.py", line 5, in <module>
from notebook.notes.models import Note
  File "/vagrant/PROJECT/notes/models.py", line 13, in <module>
class Notebook(models.Model):
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 118, in __new__
"INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class PROJECT.notes.models.Notebook doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

### Explanation:

I have an existing app called `notes`, and with the introduction of DRF I've created a new app called `api` which will handle all "api logic". In the `api` app I import the models from the `notes` app and use them where needed (serializers and views).

### My code

#### Notes app

**models.py**

```
class Notebook(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Note(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    notebook = models.ForeignKey(Notebook, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='notes')
```

#### Api app

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'api'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'notes/$', views.note_list),
    url(r'notes/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.note_detail),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from PROJECT.notes.models import Note
from .serializers import NoteSerializer


@csrf_exempt
def note_list(request):

    if request.method == "GET":
        notes = Note.objects.all()
        serializer = NoteSerializer(notes, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

    elif request.method == "POST":
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = NoteSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)


@csrf_exempt
def note_detail(request, pk):
    try:
        note = Note.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Note.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == "GET":
        serializer = NoteSerializer(note)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == "PUT":
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = NoteSerializer(note, data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        note.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

#### Root config

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^notes/', include('notes.urls')),
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
DJANGO_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (
    'rest_framework',
)

LOCAL_APPS = (
    'notes.apps.NotesConfig',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS
```

### What I've tried

I'm kinda lost here so I haven't tried a whole lot. But one of my theories is that the models in the `notes` app might not have loaded correctly or that the apps aren't loaded in the order I've listed them in `settings.py`.

I'm guessing the problem is a rookie mistake, but I can't find what I've done wrong.

I've tried to cleanup the code by removing non-relevent stuff. If something is missing, just ask and I will include it.

Comment: Please show the `NotesConfig`. Since the traceback has `from notebook.notes.models import Note`. I would expect you to have `'notebook.notes'` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, but you have `notes.apps.NotesConfig`. Replacing real values with `PROJECT` might hide the problem.

Comment: You could try changing the import to `'from notes.models import Note'`. If the app is importable as `notes` and `notebook.notes`, that suggests that there's something unusual with your Python path.